# How Do You Remove the Terminal Titlebar for Neovim?

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim, neovim

I just started trying out Neovim, so I am just getting the hang of setting it up. After installing Neovim through `sudo apt install neovim`, when I launch Neovim through either the `nvim` command, or clicking its application icon, Neovim seems to only run inside the terminal window and not on its own. As such, when it is running, it always shows "Terminal" in the titlebar, as well as the gnome terminal option menu things.

I would like to modify Neovim, if possible, to remove the titlebar in the gnome terminal window when Neovim is running, or, if possible, change Neovim so that it runs on its own, outside of the terminal window . It doesn't make sense for the titlebar of the Neovim window to say "Terminal" when I am using Neovim.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that Vim has the command `set title` which at least removes "Terminal" from the titlebar, which is a good start.